# Timeout a really long socket query

Tags: java, sockets

I am using a java sockets to connect to one of our network nodes execute commands get some data and display in an html grid.Problem is when the node is unavailable or unable to due to network problem the query does not get timed out as a result  application 
performance is severely dented.I have tried socket.sotimeout() but it does not seem to work.Below is the code given for reference.

```
public void initializeConnection(String host, int port)
            throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        if(debug)
            System.out.println((new StringBuilder()).append("connecting to host ").append(host).append(" port: ").append(port).toString());
        socket = new Socket(host, port);

        socket.setSoTimeout(6000);
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);

        in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection could not be established");
        closeConnection();
        throw e;
    }
    if(debug)
        System.out.println("Connected!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, port), timeout);
```

documentation shows:
`SocketTimeoutException` - if timeout expires before connecting